# Issues with Python 3 absolute import from script within package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I feel that this is a rather basic issue, so I'm only more upset that I wasn't able to fix it for quite some time. Say I have the following folder structure:

```
foo
|- first_module.py
|- __init__.py
|- bar
   |- second_module.py
   |- __init__.py
```

foo and bar being directories. In first_module.py I have an absolute import statement referring to second_module.py:

```
import foo.bar.second_module
```

Now, if run first_module.py as a script (foo being the working directory), I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo':
```

Please, can anyone explain to me why this is the case? I've checked that foo is in sys.path. I've read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and a bunch of other stackoverflow posts. I think it might have to do with the interpreter not knowing that first_module.py is part of the package foo. But how can I fix this?

Comment: Or you can add the parent directory of foo to sys.path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that trying `import foo.bar.second_module` would require that your directory structure have a `foo` directory as a child of your current working directory, i.e.:

```
foo
|- first_module.py
|- __init__.py
|- foo
   |- bar
      |- second_module.py  <-- at foo.bar.second_module
      |- __init__.py
```

To keep your original directory structure and import successfully, simply change your `first_module` to use `import bar.second_module` instead.

> why this is the case?

When `import`ing, you should think of the dots `.` as analogous to path separators. Thus, using the following sample layout:

```
foo
|- first.py
|- bar
   |- second.py
   |- third.py
```

If you want to `import` module `second.py` from `first.py`, you must write `import bar.second`. If you want to import `third` from `second`, you can write `import third` because they're both in the same directory.

Note that you'd still need to write `import bar.third` if trying to import from `first`.

Comment: Thanks @ray that solves the issue. I have a quick follow up: What I'm actually trying to do is write a small command line tool for natural language processing. In this use case, first_module is intended to be the script  which accesses all the back-end function.  Does this mean that, by design, I have to put the script outside the package?

Comment: @buechel Not really. You can always add a sub-directory with the same name as the top-level directory, but I'd (personally) avoid having something like `foo/foo` layout. Instead, just be mindful of the `import` lines in the top-level module.